# Hola buenas se deben ordenar 10000000 de datos, por el método de burbuja recursivo (obligado) y me da el siguiente error:

Tags: c, stack

Process terminated with status -1073741571

el lenguaje utilizado es c (también obligado), por obligación se debe ordenar el puntero por el método burbuja recursivo, puntero el cual se leyeron los datos desde un archivo txt y estoy usando el IDE CODEBLOCKS como compilador, cualquier posible solución es bienvenida ;D

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define LINEAS 10000000
#define NOMBRE_ARCHIVO "archivo.txt"
void swap(int* arr, int i, int j)
{
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
void bubbleSort(int* arr, int n)
{
    if (n == 1)return;
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
            swap (arr, i, arr[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    bubbleSort(arr, n - 1);
}
int main()
{
     int* p = malloc(LINEAS*sizeof(p));

     int i,a;

     FILE *archivo = fopen(NOMBRE_ARCHIVO, "r");
     for(i=0;i<LINEAS;i++){
    fscanf(archivo,"%d",&a);
    p[i]=a;
     }
    fclose(archivo);
    double time_spent = 0.0;
    clock_t begin = clock();
    bubbleSort(p,LINEAS);
     clock_t end = clock();
     time_spent += (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
      printf("The elapsed time is %f seconds", time_spent);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate en la llamada a `swap`:

```
swap (arr, i, arr[i + 1]);
//            ~~~~~~~~~~
```

La función espera un puntero y **dos índices**, tu le estás pasando un puntero, un índice y **un valor**. El problema viene cuando `swap` usa ese valor como un índice, en cuanto el valor no esté en el rango 0-10000000 accederás a posiciones que no pertenecen al array.

Lo dicho, en la llamada a `swap` debes pasar dos índices:

```
swap (arr, i, i + 1);
```